# Images not showing despite correct path

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**MORE DETAILS:**

The file structure is as follows:

[image]

Here it is on my server:

[image]

**ORIGINAL:** So, I'm building out the "projects" section of a website, and for some reason the images that should show aren't showing. The paths are correct but some of the images just won't appear.

I've renamed the images, changed the paths, placed in different folders but to no avail. Any suggestions? Hovering over the code in the IDE shows the image path works.

The actual site being worked on is: http://mikestrawmedia.com/index.html

[image: Image Path shows proper image]

That said, hovering over the image path in dev tools when testing and even when pushing the update shows no image.

[image: Dev Tools Path]

[image: What should appear on the right, refuses to appear]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="portfolioContainer wow fadeInUp delay-04s">
        <div class="Portfolio-box webdesign">
            <a href="http://bbsfl.mikestrawmedia.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/projects/bbsfl.PNG" alt=""></a> 
            <h3>BBSFL -- Sim Football League</h3>
            <p>Web Design</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Portfolio-box branding">
            <a href="img/projects/ms_logo2.png" target="_blank"><img src="img/projects/mslogo.png" alt=""></a>  
            <h3>Mike Straw Media</h3>
            <p>Branding</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Portfolio-box branding">
            <a href="img/projects/SGOOverlay.png" target="_blank"><img src="img/projects/SGOOverlay.png" alt=""></a>
            <h3>Sports Gamers Online</h3>
            <p>Branding</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: including live link to your project would be helpful.

Comment: Try giving the full image source with host. ie 
 `http://www.yoursite.com/image_path`

Comment: Can you try doing right click on the image you can see, and click on 'open image in a new tab/window'. That would give you the url from the server to the image you can see. Then try typing the name of the image you can't see and check if  such image shows on the browser. That might give you a hint of where to start.

Comment: @HoracioCoronel Did that. When replacing the name to the image I can't see, I get 404 not found. That said, it's on the server and in the right directory

Comment: show us your direcory structure of the images stored and the html ?

Comment: @M.Straw I checked the image and it seems like an empty image. Check the screen capture https://imgur.com/a/7waemrD

Comment: Hey guys I checked the link it is working !

Comment: @M.Straw check your images size also, they seem to be way bigger for the web and the size you intended them to be seen. 6.5MB for an image is a little bit to much... try downsizing them. https://imgur.com/a/LmpgCj0

Comment: Yea, the size is going to be taken care of after I fix this main issue.

Comment: I think that's your main issue, if you take a look at this other image on your site (4.9MB) it won't display on the browser, http://mikestrawmedia.com/img/projects/bbsfl2.png

Comment: @HoracioCoronel so, IIUC, the image size should be smaller? Is that something I can change to overwrite or no?

Comment: @M.Straw if you don't need transparency on the images seems like an overkill to have png. You should try creating jpg images and also lower the dpi. I just checked, one of your images has a 600dpi, even though it's only 350px wide. Check this image I resized on Photoshop, it's the same size you need but only 72dpi. https://imgur.com/a/BBMgBOy try replacing that image and see if it works. The new image is only 30KB against 4.9MB of your original image.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it was the image size. By optimizing the images for web, they loaded right up. Thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: Glad I could help!